# Is it unsafe to return a variable by `std::move` in stack? (Compiler shows warning for this)

Tags: c++, move, rvalue-reference

I read many answer that local variable can be safely returned by `std::move`.
But when I tried it, compiler shows warning like below.

```
class MyClass {};

MyClass&& func() {
    MyClass c;
    return std::move(c);
}

int main() {
    func();
}


warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'c' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return std::move(c);
                     ^
```

What is wrong with above code?

Comment: `MyClass&&` is just a kind of reference like `MyClass&`. `std::move` is just a cast to an rvalue reference, it doesn't actually do anything. You are returning a reference to a function local object which is incorrect.

Comment: To be more clear: you are returning reference to object which lifetimes just ended. This leads to Undefined Behavior (bug in code). You should just return a value and do not use `std::move` since this would break Return Value Optimization (RVO) which is now obligatory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are right.  I might confuse with `MyClass func() { .... return std::move(c); }`. If return type is `MyClass&&`, it does nothing.

Comment: Local variables should be returned by value to allow named return value optimization - so if you are trying to move for performance reasons, don't. Compiler will do it even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code sample, you **return a (rvalue-)reference to a local variable**. Since the local variable is destroyed after the function call is completed, using such returned value is **Undefined Behaviour**.

---

On the other hand, if you **return by value instead** (which you should), using `std::move` is probably not a good idea.

Indeed, due to NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization), the compiler is allowed to perform copy elision in order to avoid an unnecessary copy/move.

Actually, NRVO is not mandatory so the move constructor ***may*** be called (but in practice, it won't happen since most compiler will perform the optimization).

Knowing that, if you explicitly use `std::move`, since the move constructor may have side effect, you make your variable not eligible for NRVO, which translates the above *"move constructor **may** be called"* into *"move constructor **will** be called"*, **which is a pessimization**.

Thus, except if you definitely want to call the move constructor (e.g. for a specific behavior implemented inside), you should not return with `std::move`.
In other words, if it's only a performance concern, the compiler will do it better than you with copy elision.

Consequently, the right version would be:

```
MyClass func() // Return by value
{
    MyClass c;
    /*
        Do whatever you want with c.
    */

    return c; // NRVO (copy elision)
}
```